# Paperclip android apk attachment validations in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am working on a rails 3.2 application which demand a user to upload an android apk file, i have tried all the validations i can think of, in paperclip documentations, the best way to go about it is to validate with

```
validates_attachment_content_type :binary,
:content_type =>    ['application/vnd.android.package-archive'],
:message => "can only be android application."
```

but paperclip is saving apk's content_type as application/octet-stream but this content type is too generic, i need a strict validation on the android apk attachment.
i'm using the latest paperclip version by having this in my Gemfile.

```
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
```

help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

see if this works for you:

```
validates_format_of :apk_file_name, :with => %r{\.(apk)$}i
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :app, :content_type => ['application/vnd.android.package-archive']
```

Comment: That wouldn't work either, the name of the attachment field in my application is binary and not app